# ntlm authorization in java on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, oracle, authorization, weblogic, ntlm

Please help,
I searched the whole Internet and nothing helped. In short:
When I try with overriding the Authenticator like (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html example):

```
    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
        // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
        System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()));
    }
```

It works from NetBeans but not when I put that standalone app on weblogic server. It just does not continue the NTML auth. When I look with wireshark i just see the start of ntml negotiation and then it stops.
I tried all other custom libraries like jcifs, but i can't make it work.
Anybody?

Comment: Is the standalone WebLogic server running as a Windows service? What user is it running under?

Comment: No... weblogic runs on red hat  OS. user that it's running under is ok, it has needed privileges i checked it....

Comment: In the meantime i found this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15911794/2347418
but not jet sure how to use it...

Comment: @Neo did you ever solve this? Stuck with the same problem. Authenticating against NTLM from Java works fine a standalone app and in a webapp deployed to Tomcat but it fails if deployed in Weblogic.