# soap header issues <wsse:Security> header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, http-headers, soapui

So, I've been given a WSDL link through which I have to consume soap services.As I'm running my java code I get an Exception  : Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error was discovered processing the  header
After trying Testsuit from soupUi I'm receiving the same error 

                  ns1:InvalidSecurity         An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
      
   

I'm pretty new to SOAP web services.Can anyone please guide me steps how to add headers in java code for authentication.
Thank you :)

Comment: Can you give the stack trace of the SOAPFaultException ?

Comment: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.isPermitted(Unknown Source)
 at com.prakash.soap.test.main(test.java:69)

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071366/java-web-service-client-basic-authentication

Comment: Actually I do not even  have the format how the data will be send through the header :(

Comment: Why do you need the format ? It's just a username and password right ? JAX-WS should do it all for you with the linked stackoverflow answer.

Comment: As I said I'm preety new to SOAP web services.Can you please tell me how to check which famework its using cuz As far as I've done till now .I have extracted the java classes using wsimport and copied them to my standalone java-project.

Comment: And if needed to add JAX-WS how'd be that done.

Comment: Like you said, you have used wsimport to import the WSDL, so it's already JAX-WS and JAX-WS is apart of your Java install.  Follow tutorials like http://www.javatips.net/blog/2012/09/java-wsimport-tool-example

Comment: So I used this 
LookupService lookupservice=new LookupService();
 
Lookup port = lookupservice.getLookupPort();

 BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
 prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userName);
 prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,userPassword);

 port.getAllServices();
ANd I'm Still getting the same error at port.getAllServices()

Comment: Try the same call with SOAP UI first and verify that it works

Comment: Still cant. Same error
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring>An error was discovered processing the &lt;wsse:Security> header</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Can you please guide me how and where to specify the username and password?I'm stuck and i need it to be done.Thank You

Comment: Did you try Soap UI first as I suggested ?

Comment: Yes I did.I also have posted the response I've got from server

Comment: At the bottom left order of the SOAP UI request window, there is a "Auth" button. Add a basic type auth with your user name and password

Comment: Yes I've done that and I'm getting the response like
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring>An error was discovered processing the &lt;wsse:Security> header</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Then you must ask another question on Stackoverflow if this happens with Soap ui

Comment: I have added soapui tag to this and edited the question.Lets hope some experts can help me out with this issue ad thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have Fixed this issue I had to manually add custom headers to my request  message. But for this I had to  detach   previous header and then append my custom header to the request message.
 I hope next time someone getting this type of exception may get some help from this.