# Jaxb login to service

Tags: jaxb

I have a web service and I want unmarshall and generate java classes. To reach my web services I need to login with basic authentication. So whenever I try to run

```
xjc -d src https:/www.example.com/ws/service?wsdl -wsdl -verbose
```

I get HTTP response code : 401 for url : https:/www.example.com/ws/service?wsdl

I have proxy as well but I use

```
 -httpproxy myusername:password@proxyserver:proxyport
```

Is there any way to authenticate my account first?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795362/generate-java-classes-from-a-wsdl-url-with-basic-authentication

Comment: `xjc` does not support basic auth. Download WSDL and compile it locally.