# SOAP Services are working in SOAP UI but not Working via Code in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, basic-authentication, soap-client

Soap services are working fine after passing the parameters username and password under authentication tab in Soap UI but not working from java code.

Please find the Code as below:

```
ServicesLocator sl = new ServicesLocator();
ServicesSoapProxy proxy = new ServicesSoapProxy();
ServicesSoap serviceSoap = sl.getServicesSoap();

//Service s = new Service();
//Port port = s.getPort(); // if tried using service object s but s.getPort not coming in my code

Port port = (Port) sl.getPort(proxy.getEndpoint(),ServicesSoap.class);
BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");

//then calling SOAP Service 
serviceSoap.callExternalSOAPSERVICE();
```

Error as shown below:

```
faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (401)Unauthorized
faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
      {}:return code:  401
```

Please suggest on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071366/java-web-service-client-basic-authentication

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: you need to add your code!

Comment: @Abhishek Kothari,@ Laurens  code pasted..please check

Comment: @Jonathan Barbero please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Set HTTP Header,
Authorization Basic "base64encoded username/password".

Something like below.

```
String authString = "username" + ":" + "password";
String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());

//Get the HTTP Header and set it like below.

objectXXX.header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);"

//Call your service, now
```